# Unity добавление к существующему тексту текст

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Как реализовать нечто подобное набора номера телефона, есть кнопки 1,2 - 9, и поле текста как дисплей, нажимаю на кнопку 3 в поле записалось 3, нажимаю на 2 записался 2, но 3 не стерся, без перезаписи, а сохраняется порядок : 32
Язык c#.

Answer (score -1):

Понял

```
    string Displaynumber;
    public void PlayNumber(int i)
    {
        Displaynumber = Displaynumber + i;
        DisplayNumber.text = Displaynumber.ToString();  
    }
```

Comment: Что это за сложности? DisplayNumber.text+=i.ToString() - нет?